# PIG UDF load .gz file failed

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, gzip, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I wrote my UDF to load file into Pig. It works well for loading text file, however, now I need also be able to read `.gz` file. I know I can unzip the file then process, but I want just read `.gz` file without to unzip it.

I have my UDF extends from `LoadFunc`, then in my costom input file `MyInputFile extends TextInputFormat`. I also Implemented `MyRecordReader`. Just wondering if extends `TextInputFormat` is the problem? I tried `FileInputFormat`, still cannot read the file. Anyone wrote UDF read data from `.gz` file before?

Comment: `TextInputFormat` can handle gzip files. Have a look at its RecordReader's (`LineRecordReader`) `initialize()` method where the proper CompressionCodec is initialized. Also note that gzip files aren't splittable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. If it is not splittable then I think I will consider to unzip it first. Much appreciate if you can point out some best practice for pre-unzip the file then load in to PIG. Like what is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing the data size the easiest way would be to store your data _uncompressed_ on hdfs. you may also repack it using a splittable format (`LZO`). How to extract gzip file; local disk->HDFS, see: 
http://bigdatanoob.blogspot.hu/2011/07/copy-and-uncompress-file-to-hdfs.html . If already on hdfs: `hadoop fs -cat /data/data.gz | gzip -d | hadoop fs -put - /data/data.txt`

Comment: How about from S3? Same as it is already on HDFS? Just wondering can you put your comment as an answer? So I can accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextInputFormat` handles gzip files *as well*. Have a look at its RecordReader's (`LineRecordReader`) initialize() method where the proper *CompressionCodec* is initialized. Also note that gzip files **aren't splittable** (even if they are located on S3) so you might either need to use a splittable format (e.g: LZO) or an uncompressed data to exploit the desired level of parallel processing.

If your gzipped data is stored locally you can uncompress and copy it to hdfs in one step as described [here](http://bigdatanoob.blogspot.hu/2011/07/copy-and-uncompress-file-to-hdfs.html). Or if it's already on hdfs 
`hadoop fs -cat /data/data.gz | gzip -d | hadoop fs  -put - /data/data.txt` would be more convenient.

Comment: By the way, if in HDFS and want to read .gz file from S3 and save into HDFS, then run `hadoop fs -cat s3n://yourbuckets/yourfile.gz | gzip -d > yourfile.txt`.